To add product filter in Product in category tab section grid magento2
To add a product grid with filters in the custom category tab section in Magento 2.4.6, you need to follow a structured approach to ensure the product grid with filters is displayed correctly in the category edit section.

category_form.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="custom_products_fieldset" sortOrder="80">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Custom Products</label>
    </settings>
    <container name="custom_products_container">
        <!--uiComponent name="custom_category_products_listing"/-->
    </container>
</fieldset>




Please include more details and clarify.

category tab section add custom tab and show product grid show with all filters @RonakRathod

you want to display the selected category on the product grid Correct?

@RonakRathod update our question again so please check
